# How to tell Spring to check again the ConditionalOnBean during the app runtime?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-bean

On some beans, I'm using `ConditionalOnBean` (`a` and `b` in the example). At the time the app starts, the bean that is conditional on it does not exist. Therefore, the bean (`yoni` in the example) under the annotation (`ConditionalOnBean`) are not initialized and are not processed by Spring.
During the course of running the app, the bean is dynamically added to the context (see `addYoni` in the example). In order to initialize the beans that now pass the conditions (`a` and `b` in the example), I need to tell Spring to check all the conditionals again. *It should be noted that in the real world I do not know which classes are under the relevant condition (in fact, some of them have not yet been written).*

If it is possible, how can it be done?

```
@ConditionalOnBean(name = "yoni")
@Service
public class a {
.
.
.
}

@ConditionalOnBean(name = "yoni")
@Service
public class b {
.
.
.
}

@Service
public class d {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void addYoni(){
        ConfigurableApplicationContext configContext = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext;
        DefaultListableBeanFactory beanRegistry = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) configContext.getBeanFactory();
        beanRegistry.registerSingleton("yoni", yoni());
        
        // What Should be written here to cause Spring to check and to inject the under-conditions classes into the application context?
    }
    
    public Rab yoni() {
        Rab rab = new rab();
        .
        .
        .        
        return rab;  
    } 
}
```

Comment: That isn't possible and won't be supported either (there was a question asking the same a couple of weeks ago).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thx for the answer. Could you please explain why it won't be supported

Comment: Because the whole bean isn't there (those conditional ones) and reinstating them would require a full restart of the app instead of a simple refresh of a bean. On a different note do you really want to change/add beans at runtime as that can be quite dangerous imho. There is an answer/comment somewhere explaining that and linking to the rejected GitHub issue as well. But have no luck in finding it yet .

Comment: @M.Deinum Thx for the answer. Refreshing only the bean could be a great idea but the problem is that there is no such bean due to the `@ConditionalOnBean` performed at the beginning.

Comment: Which is exactly why it won't work because the bean isn't there.

Comment: @M.Deinum please have a look on my answer

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I found a way to do so. It required to look for the classes with the annotation `ConditionalOnBean` and create a bean from them. Here is the code (class `d` in the question):

```
@Service
public class d {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;


    public void addC(){
        ConfigurableApplicationContext configContext = (ConfigurableApplicationContext) applicationContext;
        DefaultListableBeanFactory beanRegistry = (DefaultListableBeanFactory) configContext.getBeanFactory();
        beanRegistry.registerSingleton("yoni", yoni());

        ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider componentProvider =
                new ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider(false);
        componentProvider.addIncludeFilter(new AnnotationTypeFilter(ConditionalOnBean.class));
        Set<BeanDefinition> candidateComponents = componentProvider.findCandidateComponents("base.project.package");
        candidateComponents.forEach(beanDefinition -> {
            String className = beanDefinition.getBeanClassName().substring(beanDefinition.getBeanClassName().lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
            String beanName = Character.toLowerCase(className.charAt(0)) + className.substring(1);
            if (!applicationContext.containsBean(beanName))
            {
                Map<String, Object> annotationAttributes = ((ScannedGenericBeanDefinition) beanDefinition).getMetadata().getAnnotationAttributes(
                        ConditionalOnBean.class.getName());
                String[] beansDependsOn = (String[]) annotationAttributes.getOrDefault("name", new String[]{});
                if ((beansDependsOn.length == 1) && (beansDependsOn[0].contentEquals("yoni")) {
                    try {
                        beanRegistry.createBean(Class.forName(beanDefinition.getBeanClassName()));
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        log.error("Failed to init the class : [" + beanDefinition.getBeanClassName() + "]\n", e);
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public Rab yoni() {
        Rab rab = new rab();

        return rab;
    }
}
```